# What does homomorphism mean in the GLOVE paper?

Tags: machine-learning

It is mentioned in the [GloVe: Global Vectors for Word Representation](https://nlp.stanford.edu/pubs/glove.pdf). It says: [image]

where $w_i$, $w_j$ and $\tilde{w}_k$ are all word vectors and $F$ is just an unknown function. The author then assumes $F$ as $exp$. What is homomorphism exactly? Why equation (4) can make $F((w_i - w_j)^T\tilde{w}_k)$ homomorphism?

Comment: This is about mathematics, specifically algebra, not about statistics. @Xi'an's answer is spot on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

copying [verbatim from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphism)

> A *homomorphism* is a map between two algebraic structures of the same
>   type (that is of the same name), that preserves the operations of the
>   structures. This means a map ${\displaystyle f:A\to B}$ between two
>   sets $A$, $B$ equipped with the same structure such that, if $∗$ is an
>   operation of the structure (supposed here, for simplification, to be a
>   binary operation), then $${\displaystyle f(x*y)=f(x)*f(y)}$$ for every
>   pair $x, y$ of elements of $A$

Comment: Specifically, here we have a [group homomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_homomorphism) between the additive group of the reals and the multiplicative group of the nonzero reals. It must satisfy that the neutral element $0$ of the first group must be mapped to the neutral element $1$ of the second one, $F(0)=1$, and that it commutes with the respective group operations, in this case $F(x+y)=F(x)\times F(y)$.